# (negative to affirmative) "we could not but pocket the insult"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, modal-verbs, grammatical-case

When we do negative to affirmative, we always use 'must' in the place of 'can not but'. I further know that we cannot use 'must' in the place of 'could not but' because 'could not but' is a past form. So can I use 'had to' in the place of 'could not but'?

Comment: *Must* has a past form, too. It's *must*.

Comment: "We *had to* pocket the insult" sounds perfectly acceptable to me. I'm not sure if there is a better way to express it.

Comment: We don't "do negative to affirmative" in English. Negation is not a simple matter of grammar; it's very very complex. And _could not but_ is an archaic expression not used in Modern English. Where are they telling you all this nonsense?

Comment: *We could not but pocket the insult > we **were unable to do anything** but pocket the insult > We were unable to do anything **except** to pocket the insult. > We **had no choice except [the choice] to accept** the insult. > **The only choice [that] we had** was to accept the insult.* The negative thus depends upon which you wish to negate.

Comment: I disagree with all of the premises in the question. In fact, it's even internally inconsistent, because the last sentence suggests a denial to the first statement.

Comment: How does one pocket an insult?

Comment: @RegDwight Are you saying that 'The Germans were not far off the town ... we must organise our defences' is / was acceptable? I seem to remember 'must needs' used this way.

Comment: @JohnLawler Haha, it's like _swallowing_ an insult, I suppose, except that with a _pocketed_ insult, one intends to retrieve it for analysis or return.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **had to**  + bare infinitive is a perfectly idiomatic way of  expressing the idea of past obligation or necessity, including having no other choice because of external or self-imposed constraint.

> I had to go to the dentist.
>
> I had to demur.
>
> I had to get my car fixed.
>
> I had to swallow my pride.

**could not but** is listed in dictionaries but [its heyday was over 200 years ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=could%20not%20but&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), although it is still in use today.